# How to create a DialogPreference programatically?

Tags: android, android-preferences

The background of my question is that I'd like to create a menu just like the "Wifi Networks" settings on my Samsung Galaxy S9000. The menu shows a list of known networks and has one additional list entry with the title "Add new network". If you click on it, fill out the dialog and hit "Ok" you get a new list item. The "Add new network" item is still there after this procedure.

My approach is to have a *PreferenceScreen* with one *AdressDialogPreference* which is a subclass of *DialogPreference*. The title of this preference is set to "Add new IP Address". When the user opens the dialog and enters values, the title of the *AddressDialogPreference* changes from "Add new IP Address" to the value the user entered in the dialog, e.g. "192.168.1.1".

But now I need a new *AddressDialogPreference* with the title "Add new IP Address", because the user may want to add more ip addresses. That is where I'm stuck. I tried the following:

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {

    if(!positiveResult)
        return;

    (...)

    PreferenceScreen ps = (PreferenceScreen)pm.findPreference("validIPs");      
    ps.addPreference(new AddressDialogPreference(getContext(), attr ));
}
```

But I have no idea where I can get/create an appropriate *AttributeSet* (the  *attr* parameter). I cannot write a constructor without the *AttributeSet* because the base class *DialogPreference* requires an *AttributeSet*.

I tried to create an AttributeSet via *Xml.asAttributeSet(XmlPullParser)* but I have no clue what to feed to the *XmlPullParser*. The attributeCount was always -1 which is obviously wrong. The whole approach via a parser seems to me way to complicated.

The target API level is 8.

Excerpt from preferences.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/validIPsHeadline"
android:summary="@string/validIPsSummary" 
android:dependency="restrictIPs"
android:key="validIPs"> 

<com.websliders.preferences.AddressDialogPreference
android:title="@string/defaultIPHeadline" 
android:summary="@string/defaultIPSummary" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant but this is how I loaded an AttributeSet into a SeekBarPreference (from http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-seekbar-preference ), which is also derived from the DialogPreference class.

In your PreferenceActivity:

```
public PreferenceScreen getPreferenceScreen(String title, String summary) {
    // Root
    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

    PreferenceCategory inlinePrefCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    inlinePrefCat.setTitle("DNA");
    root.addPreference(inlinePrefCat);

    //This is where you load the AttributeSet 
    //from the res/layouts/seekbarpreference_layout.xml file
    Preference editTextPref;
    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(R.layout.seekbarpreference_layout);
    AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

    editTextPref = new SeekBarPreference(this, attributes);


    editTextPref.setKey(title);
    editTextPref.setTitle(title);
    editTextPref.setSummary(summary);
    //editTextPref.setText(text)
    inlinePrefCat.addPreference(editTextPref);

    return root;
}
```

And this is the "res/layouts/seekbarpreference_layout.xml" file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.hlidskialf.android.preference.SeekBarPreference
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:key="duration"
        android:title="Duration of something"
        android:summary="How long something will last"
        android:dialogMessage="Something duration"
        android:defaultValue="5"
        android:text=" minutes"
        android:max="60"
        />
```

If it's not working for you, perhaps you are missing a required attribute in the XML file?